# Android Studio Augmented Image camera is blurry

Tags: android, augmented-reality, augmentedimage

hi anyone have experience and fix blurry camera of augmented image in android studio?

here is the sample result

[image]

Tried to change this part but still blurred

```
private void configureSession() {
    Config config = new Config(session);
    config.setFocusMode(Config.FocusMode.AUTO);
    if (!setupAugmentedImageDatabase(config)) {
      messageSnackbarHelper.showError(this, "Could not setup augmented image database");
    }
    session.configure(config);
  }
```